# I can't read strings written by the user

Tags: javascript, string

I am not able to read characters, strings or numbers. I'm starting to learn js and maybe it's an easy question but I cant answer it by myself. The code I'm using is:

```
var main = function()
{
    "use strict";
    var stdout = require("system").stdout;
    var stdin = require("system").stdin;
    stdout.write( "What is your name? " );
    var name = stdin.readLine();
    stdout.writeLine( "Hello, " + name );
}();
```

Thanks for your help and sorry if this question is quite silly.

Comment: Pure JavaScript doesn't have require("system"). Are you using phantomjs or ringojs? Please specify.

Comment: Hi, i'm using ringojs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla Javascript doesn't support "read strings". However, if you have an html document, you could grab the input from a text box:

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the doc on how to use readline in Node --https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline:

```
var main = function()
{
    "use strict";
    var readline = require('readline');

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question("What is your name? ", function(answer) {
      console.log("Hello ", answer);
      rl.close();
    });
}();
```